# Lucene 3.6.2 search for desktop application

Tags: java, lucene, derby

I have a desktop application that uses the lucene 3.6.2 library 
to search multiple fields in a java derby database. 
When a word is entered for a search , the lucene system returns the 
 matches to the word. On the other hand when I enter a string that is 
not a complete word but rather a piece of a larger word lucene returns 
no match for the string.

for example :
 "national" returns the available matches

but a string "natio" does not return any result.

I want to be able to enter a string

"natio" then lucene will return all "natio*" as the matching results.

below are code snippets from the application.

```
this is a the code that creates the lucene in-memory director

     Directory index = new RAMDirectory();
            StandardAnalyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(matchVersion);
            IndexWriterConfig IWConfig = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_36, analyzer);
            IndexWriter iw = new IndexWriter(index,IWConfig) ;


 //Connection to DB
  con = DriverManager.getConnection(host, uName, uPass);     
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
     String sql = "SELECT * FROM APP.REGISTRY";
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

  //creating the docuetns      
         rs.beforeFirst();
         while(rs.next()) {
         doc = new Document();
         doc.add(new Field("subject",rs.getString("SUBJECT"),Field.Store.YES,Field.Index.ANALYZED));
         doc.add(new Field("letter_from",rs.getString("LETTER_FROM"),Field.Store.YES,Field.Index.ANALYZED));
       iw.addDocument(doc);
         }


//Oen the index 
           IndexReader ir = IndexReader.open(index);


           //create the searcher object
            IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(ir);
            QueryParser queryParser = new MultiFieldQueryParser(Version.LUCENE_36,
                    new String[]{"subject","letter_from","remarks","office_dispatched_to"}, analyzer);
            Query query = queryParser.parse(qString);
```

Comment: check the link http://www.lucenetutorial.com/lucene-query-syntax.html

Comment: @faisalabdulai, you can post the solution here and accept it as an answer yourself. It's legal to do this in StackOverflow.com and actually it is encouraged.